# Getting a switch Checked event to fire in the same way as a Click event with mvvmcross

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I've got an mvvmcross project for Android in development and have recently changed part of the UI to have a switch instead of a button to remove an item from a wish list. By default, the switch is set to On. In the button version, when the button is pressed, the item is removed instantly.

The button was bound using Click RemoveCommand whereas the the switch is bound using Checked RemoveCommand within the designer.

The button works fine and removes the item, but the switch throws a binding warning that that target property is readonly. What I'm trying to do is when the switch is changed, to remove the item from the wish list in the same way clicking the button would.

Is there a way I can get the checked event to operate in the same way as the Click event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest answers:

- I think that `Checked` is a binding for a boolean property - so you can bind `Checked` on your view to a boolean on your ViewModel (and then handle some logic in the `set` handler if you need to).
- Alternatively, if you want a simple no-parameter `Command` binding, then you can just use `Click`.

---

If you wanted to do a `Command<bool>` binding then you could create one quite quickly using the code from https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/c306ba37afd9024f68b7a4f1fedcaf4cf7d01b8d/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Droid/Target/MvxCompoundButtonCheckedTargetBinding.cs and https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/c306ba37afd9024f68b7a4f1fedcaf4cf7d01b8d/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Droid/Target/MvxViewClickBinding.cs as a template - something like:

```
    using System.Reflection;
    using Android.Widget;
    using Cirrious.CrossCore.Platform;
    using Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Bindings.Target;

    namespace MyApp.Ext.Target
    {
        public class MyCompoundButtonCheckedTargetBinding
            : MvxAndroidTargetBinding
        {
            private ICommand _command;
            private IDisposable _canExecuteSubscription;
            private readonly EventHandler<EventArgs> _canExecuteEventHandler;

            protected CompoundButton View
            {
                get { return (CompoundButton)Target; }
            }

            public MyCompoundButtonCheckedTargetBinding(View view)
                : base(target, targetPropertyInfo)
            {
                _canExecuteEventHandler = new EventHandler<EventArgs>(OnCanExecuteChanged);
                SubscribeToEvents();
            }

            public override MvxBindingMode DefaultMode
            {
                get { return MvxBindingMode.OneWay; }
            }

            public override Type TargetType
            {
                get { return typeof(ICommand); }
            }

            public override void SubscribeToEvents()
            {
                var compoundButton = View;
                if (compoundButton == null)
                {
                    MvxBindingTrace.Trace(MvxTraceLevel.Error,
                                          "Error - compoundButton is null in MvxCompoundButtonCheckedTargetBinding");
                    return;
                }

                _subscribed = true;
                compoundButton.CheckedChange += CompoundButtonOnCheckedChange;
            }

            private void RefreshEnabledState()
            {
                var view = View;
                if (view == null)
                    return;

                var value = view.Checked;

                var shouldBeEnabled = false;
                if (_command != null)
                {
                    shouldBeEnabled = _command.CanExecute(value);
                }
                view.Enabled = shouldBeEnabled;
            }

            private void OnCanExecuteChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                RefreshEnabledState();
            }

            protected override void SetValueImpl(object target, object value)
            {
                if (_canExecuteSubscription != null)
                {
                    _canExecuteSubscription.Dispose();
                    _canExecuteSubscription = null;
                }
                _command = value as ICommand;
                if (_command != null)
                {
                    _canExecuteSubscription = _command.WeakSubscribe(_canExecuteEventHandler);
                }
                RefreshEnabledState();
            }

            private void CompoundButtonOnCheckedChange(object sender, CompoundButton.CheckedChangeEventArgs args)
            {
                if (_command == null)
                    return;

                var value = args.IsChecked; /* TODO - check this name... */

                if (!_command.CanExecute(value))
                    return;

                _command.Execute(value);
            }

            protected override void Dispose(bool isDisposing)
            {
                if (isDisposing)
                {
                    var view = View;
                    if (view != null)
                    {
                        view.CheckedChange -= CompoundButtonOnCheckedChange;
                    }
                    if (_canExecuteSubscription != null)
                    {
                        _canExecuteSubscription.Dispose();
                        _canExecuteSubscription = null;
                    }                
                }
                base.Dispose(isDisposing);
            }
        }
    }
```